# Zusammengeschriebene Adverben der Form "Fragewort+anders", analog zu "woanders"

Tags: spelling, adverb, compound

*Woanders* hat sowohl einen Eintrag auf [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/woanders) als auch im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/woanders).

Bei DWDS wird es als *Zusammenrückung* beschrieben.

Etwas gehobener existiert dies auch als *anderswo*, was ebenso als *zusammengeschoben* beschrieben wird.

Soweit so gut. Nur was ist mit vergleichbaren Konstruktionen wie *wer anders* oder *wann anders*? Interessanterweise listet DWDS auch die (in meinen Augen seltenere) Konstruktionen *anderswohin* und der Duden *woandersher*.

In meinen Augen scheint dies etwas willkürliche, dass manche Konstruktionen so gelistet sind und andere nicht. Das Argument "Sprache ist nunmal lebending und Logik hilft nicht immer weiter" möchte ich in diesem Falle nach 2 Rechtschreibreformen zurückweisen. Wenn man *wo anders* zu *woanders* zusammenschiebt, dann spricht nichts dagegen, das nicht auch für *wann anders* zu tun. An dieser Stelle lassen wir exotischere Konstruktionen wie *anderswann* noch außen vor.

[Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weranders%2C+wer+anders%2C+woanders%2C+wo+anders&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3) zeigt, dass *woanders* deutlich häufiger verwendet wird als *wo anders*, aber dahingegen *wer anders* viel häufiger als *weranders*. Also ein komplett umgekehrtes Verhältnis.

Meine (stark zusammenhängenden) Fragen sind also:

1. Ist *wannanders*/*anderswann*, *weranders/anderswer* usw. eine akzeptable Schreibweise<sup>1</sup>?
2. Falls sie nicht nur aus "Faulheitsgründen" nicht auf DWDS oder im Duden in zusammengeschriebener Form auftauchen, gab es diese Formen einmal und ist sie einfach aus der Mode gekommen?

<sup>1</sup>Als akzeptabel in diesem Kontext nutze ich die Definition, dass es nicht als Rechtschreibfehler gewertet wird. Ich gehe davon aus, dass es definitiv verstanden wird.

Comment: Vielleicht ist auch "wann anders" einfach zu selten um sich als Wort zu etablieren. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wann+anders%2Cwannanders%2Cwo+anders%2Cwoanders&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3
Außerdem gibt es mehrere Wörter, die mit "wo" beginnen, aber ich wüsste keines mit "wann".

Comment: Vielleicht lohnt es sich ja, ins englische Wörterbuch zu kucken: "elsewhere" ist absolut gebräuchlich, "elsewhen", "elsehow", "elsewhat", "elsewho" und "elsewhise" gibt es zwar, sind aber archaisch. An deiner Vermutung "gab es mal" könnte also was dran sein.

Comment: @CarstenS danke für die Liste. Da mag etwa dran sein, aber die gleiche Fragestellung ergibt sich nicht nur für wann+anders sondern auch für wer, und da sieht es nicht mehr so viel seltener aus: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weranders%2C+wer+anders%2C+woanders%2C+wo+anders&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: "anderswohin", "anderweitig", und andere, parallele Konstrukte stehen durchaus im Duden als *umgangssprachlich*

Comment: @infinitezero, guter Punkt

Comment: @tofro "weitig" ist allerdings kein Fragewort mehr und _weitiganders_  klingt recht falsch für meine Ohren. _woandershin_ hingegen würde in das Muster fallen, dass beide Formen existieren (Fragewort + anders und anders+Fragewort). Demnach ließe sich Frage 1 vermutlich ableiten.

Comment: Zumindest _anderswie_ hat der Duden: https://www.google.com/search?q=anderswie

Answer (score 2):

Keines der 4 Wörter wannanders, anderswann, weranders und anderswer ist eine akzeptierte Schreibweise. Alle 4 werden als Rechtschreibfehler gewertet. Google Ngram findet diese Wörter nur, weil es Texte aus Büchern scannt und es da manchmal passieren kann, dass Leerzeichen zwischen Wörtern nicht korrekt erkannt werden.

Statt "wann anders" oder "wannanders" sagt man "zu einer anderen Zeit":

- In Ordnung: "Das Buch liegt woanders." "Hast du ihn schon woanders gesucht?"
- Äquivalent, aber nicht in Ordnung: "Das Ereignis geschah wannanders." "Ist das nicht wannanders geschehen?"
- In Ordnung: "Das Ereignis geschah zu einer anderen Zeit." "Ist das nicht zu einer anderen Zeit geschehen?"

Auch die drei anderen Wörter würde man immer, wenn sie in einem Satz gerechtfertigt erscheinen würden, durch andere Formulierungen ersetzen.

Comment: Zumindest "wann anders" habe ich schon umgangssprachlich gehört, wie "lass das mal wann anders klären" oder "lass mal wann anders treffen"

Comment: Ja, "wann anders" ist hier am Rhein im mündlichen Gebrauch ziemlich häufig, statt "ein andermal" oder "ein anderes Mal".

Comment: Auch aus Baden-Württemberg kenne ich durchaus "wann anders" - aber wie gesagt nur als umgangssprachlich, nur in viel informelleren Texten als denjenigen, in denen ich "woanders" verwenden würde.

Comment: Stimme aus Österreich (geboren 1965 in Graz, 30 Jahre Steiermark (hauptsächlich Graz), 20 Jahre Wien, seit 2016 in St. Pölten.): "Wann anders" habe ich noch nie gehört oder gelesen, auch nicht aus den Mund eines deutschen Immigranten oder Touristen (von beiden gibt es reichlich in Österreich). Dabei achte ich aber sehr auf die Sprache meiner Mitmenschen. Ich glaube aber gerne, dass es Gegenden gibt, wo das gebräuchlich ist. Die meisten Deutschen die ich persönlich kenne, kommen aus NRW, Sachsen und Hamburg+Umgebung, und da scheint das ebenso ungebräuchlich zu sein wie in Österreich.

Comment: 'Das muss wer anders machen' ist durchaus gebräuchlich und auch wannanders. Hubert Schölnasts Einschätzung zum Gebrauch in Deutschland halte ich aus meiner Erfahrung für für falsch.